# Transform a series of JavaScript object keys into array(s) when they contain numbers

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, key, transform

I have this object:

```
{
  name: "Gold's Gym Venice",
  "categories[0].alias": "gyms",
  "categories[0].title": "Gyms",
  "categories[1].alias": "healthtrainers",       
  "categories[1].title": "Trainers",
  "location.state": "CA",
  "location.city": "Venice",
  "location.zip_code": "90291",
  "location.display_address[0]": "360 Hampton Dr",
  "location.display_address[1]": "Venice, CA 90291"
}
```

... and am trying to transform it into this:

```
{
    name: "Gold's Gym Venice",
    categories: [
        { alias: "gyms", title: "Gyms" },
        { alias: "healthtrainers", title: "Trainers" }
    ],
    location: {
      state: "CA",
      city: "Venice",
      zip_code: "90291",
      display_address: [ "360 Hampton Dr", "Venice, CA 90291" ]
    }
}
```

I tried both of [these](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50003862/221869) [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40578188/221869). Each gives slightly different output—the second one gets closer—but neither handles keys with square bracketed numbers/array positions properly.

What's the best way to handle this?

Comment: What language are you using? And how volatile is the structure?

Comment: Ie, how deep can these object be nested. And what happens for instance with a key like `foo[0].bar[0].baz` (if this can occur)?

Comment: @derpirscher JavaScript/ES6+ and the structure is not volatile—this was caused by a (hopefully one-time) change in an API I'm consuming. The object can be as deep as needed, and the example key you gave would be `{ foo [ bar [ { baz: ... } ] ] }`

Comment: I suggest you use a library like lodash's `_.set()` to set your object by a string path. Using a trusted library helps also protect against things like prototype pollution attacks which could occur here if you can't trust your input object.

Comment: This would work as well. Thank you. I didn't specify that I was hoping for a self-contained solution; for that reason I selected the solution @Damzaky posted. That's not to diminish that lodash code is great to learn from.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think we can use the method from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70425843/7552340), here is an example code for the example you provided:

```js
const deepSet = (obj, path, val) => {
    path = path.replaceAll("[", ".[");
    const keys = path.split(".");

    for (let i = 0; i < keys.length; i++) {
        let currentKey = keys[i];
        let nextKey = keys[i + 1];
        if (currentKey.includes("[")) {
            currentKey = parseInt(currentKey.substring(1, currentKey.length - 1));
        }
        if (nextKey && nextKey.includes("[")) {
            nextKey = parseInt(nextKey.substring(1, nextKey.length - 1));
        }

        if (typeof nextKey !== "undefined") {
            obj[currentKey] = obj[currentKey] ? obj[currentKey] : (isNaN(nextKey) ? {} : []);
        } else {
            obj[currentKey] = val;
        }

        obj = obj[currentKey];
    }
};

const result = {};

const originalObj = {
  'categories[0].alias': 'gyms',
  'categories[0].title': 'Gyms',
  'categories[1].alias': 'healthtrainers',       
  'categories[1].title': 'Trainers',
  'location.display_address[0]': '360 Hampton Dr',
  'location.display_address[1]': 'Venice, CA 90291'
};

for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(originalObj)) {
  deepSet(result, key, value);
}

console.log(result);
```

Comment: Upon running this code you can see that it leaves keys named `{ '0', '1', ... }`, rather than an array of objects. The result is very similar to the first answer linked in the question.

Comment: @Rod Boev: *it leaves keys named { '0', '1', ... }, rather than an array of objects* - you'll always get these numeric array indices when logging arrays to the console. That's how arrays work. So the answer should solve your problem.

Comment: @herrstrietzel My apologies, I must have crossed wires with a solution I was working on. I was seeing the keys as strings instead of integers. Thanks, @Damzaky!

Comment: and if the input can't be trusted, replacing `const result = {};` with `const result = Object.create(null);` or adding `Object.freeze(Object.prototype)` (noting this is a global change), might be worth considering to avoid [prototype pollution](https://learn.snyk.io/lesson/prototype-pollution/) attacks.